# Reversing view animation on Android?

Tags: android, view, translate-animation

So if I have a translation animation like

```
Animation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, OFFSET);
anim.setDuration(1000L);
anim.setAnimationListener(listener);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
```

and I apply this to a textswitcher so that given a offset, the textswitcher will move from a location, A, up or down.

My textswitcher will stay at a given location, B, after the animation due to the setfillafter.  How can I then from that location, B, reverse the animation and go back to location, A?

The Overall Question

So I'm translating a textswitcher down and then up, but of course, setfillafter only translates the bitmap of the view and not the view itself, so this may not be the best approach.  I've also tried to do an animation and then offset of the view, but that looks glitchy.  So basically, I want a view(textswitcher) which a swipe/fling down will move it down and touching(onClick) it when it's down will move it back up (same animation reversed).  How can I do this?

I know how to do the swipe/fling and onClick stuff, just not how to implement the correct animation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may want to consider adding an on touch listener to see where you touched it last, If above move up with a constant animation. This is if im understanding the question correctly.